# What options for Secure Database For Mac OS Xdevelopment (esp. Core Data)?

Tags: database, macos, cocoa, security, core-data

I am building a Cocoa application that will store customer data.  I'm currently using Core Data with SQLite store.  Unfortunately, I have not found a way to secure the database.

Even on some other Mac CRM applications on the market, you can browse to the Library/Application Support and open their databases with any SQLite Manager, like the Firefox SQLite Manager extension.  The applications have password protection, but it seems to be useless if you can just go into the database and make changes.

So:
1) Is there a way to secure the SQLite store for a Core Data application, while retaining search, aggregations, etc?
2) If not, is the lack of this ability an indication that it is deemed unnecessary to secure it because of the OS authentication?
3) Are there alternative open source databases for Mac that might be appropriate?

Thanks!
Byron

Comment: Can you clarify who/what you're trying to secure the data against?  If you're trying to secure it against your app's user, it's going to be very difficult, since running your app doesn't grant that user any additional privileges, encryption keys they can't get by inspecting your app, etc.

Comment: That is a very good question, and I don't have a good answer.  I'm not 100% sure that I need to provide any additional protection beyond what the User authentication of OSX provides since the application will live within a user's account.  My past primary dealt with MySQL and SQL Server where you had a DB password and user accounts, so it feels a little naked to me not having that layer of security within the app.  Is it typical with Mac apps to use SQLite/Core Data for apps with customer/accounting data without protecting them beyond the OS level user auth? (not talking about Credit Cards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are third-party encryption extensions for SQLite:

- http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html
- http://sqlcipher.net/

Comment: Thanks for the links, Graham.  I wasn't able to tell from a glance if they could be used with Core Data.  SEE runs $2,000 for a perpetual license, so that would be beyond my budget.  And SQLCipher appears to be an alternate compilation of SQLite, so I'm not sure how you would hook Core Data up to use it instead of standard SQLite libraries.

Comment: Either of those would probably be a good solution if Core Data isn't needed. If no better answers come in, I'll mark as answered.  Thanks again!